# Problem with data reading on android device [Xamarin Forms]

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm new in xamarin forms and I need to open/save some data. I chose interlanl storage, becosue it won't be a big database. Everything works fine I can save and then read fiel. The problem is showing when I'm trying to move the app from the computer to my smartphone. First, I don't understand why in the folder app/Android/bin/Debug (on my computer) there are two files with .apk extension. One is named "com.companyname.myapp.apk" and the other is named "com.companyname.myapp-Signed.apk". After moving these files to the main folder on my phone I can install only the second one, but after opening it on phone the app is closing immediately. I'm sure that the reason for that is reading file because when I remove the reading method from app, the app is opening normally. Another stranger thing (for me) is that when I plugged the phone into a computer using USB debugging and run the program from a visual studio everything is ok, even if I uninstall app and instal it using the file "com.companyname.myapp-Signed.apk". Here is my reading method:

```
var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "test.txt");
if (!File.Exists(path))
{
    var writer = new StreamWriter(path); 
    writer.Write("some data"); 
}
var reader = new StreamReader(path, true); 
string data;
data = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Above code is calling in constructor in MainPage.xaml.cs fiel, maybe that is important information.

Is it something in my code or the problem is in the project properties. As I read the app doesn't need any permission to works with internal storage, so I have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: have you considered adding some exception handling and logging to your app?

Comment: I plugged the phone into the computer and I checked loggs. I'm always getting an error: "File error accessing recent directory (directory doesn't exist?). Force finishing activity com.companyname.myapp/crc...c78.MainActivity" and the tag of this message is "Task Persister".

Comment: maybe you should close your write stream before trying to read?

Comment: the problem still shows up, even if I close the stream

Comment: @DawidSchneider From [Reading or Writing to files on internal storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/#reading-or-writing-to-files-on-internal-storage), you can use async version to read or write, and try again.